# Несколько владельцев домена

Tags: ispmanager

Подскажите, можно ли , создавая домен, указать как-то несколько владельцев (пользователей) или какие атрибуты нужно поставить, чтобы все пользователи имели доступ к данному сайту ?

Comment: Возможно, вы скорее найдёте ответ в документации ISP: https://docs.ispsystem.com/

Comment: Вы таки определитесь - к домену или сайту, это эпохально разные вещи и в одном случае ответ будет "нет", а в другом - "да".